Cement vs. Calcium Sulphate Screed: Which is Best for Underfloor Heating
I'm considering installing underfloor heating in my new home and am trying to decide between cement and calcium sulphate screeds. I've heard that both have their advantages, but I'm unsure which would be the better choice for my project.
I'm particularly interested in the thermal conductivity and heat retention properties of these two materials. Which one has better heat transfer efficiency, and which one retains heat longer?

Over time, materials in contact tend to the same temperature.

This sounds like a good google search question.  For heat retention, materials with high mass/density retain heat longer.  One reason you find stone/brick walls around a wood stove.  The stove cools down in hour.  The stone wall will be warm for hours/til morning.

Just to mention -- as a person with underfloor heating on 2 levels and baseboard on a third -- that a nighttime setback for energy saving is completely infeasible with the kind of thermal mass you propose to use. You'll set the thermostat to your chosen temperature in the fall and leave it there till spring. If you prefer a cooler bedroom, that must be accomplished by zoning, not by setback, and it will therefore be cooler 24x7. I have to keep my bedroom door closed around the clock all winter to keep it cool. Consider insulating the bedroom from the rest of the house for that reason.

Agree with MTA.  I went with a low mass hydronic solution - works with setbacks.  No overheating.  Heats up quick.  Warmboards is awesome especially if you can use it as your subfloor on new build.
